What is this usage of んじゃない? is it imperative negative?

The character is telling this to a collage who is letting stay at his place.
My reading from context is: You are living here NOT because you are a client I invited, but because you are a host."
But why is んじゃない here used? Usually verb + んじゃない is imperative negative, right?

This 招いてんじゃない is short for 招いているのではない, which is not a negative imperative but a rather simple negative sentence with an explanatory-の:

招いているのではない
"It's not that I've invited you"
招いてるのではない (ている → てる)
招いてるんじゃない (の → ん; では → じゃ)
招いてんじゃない (/r/ + vowel + ん → ん)
招いてんじゃねえ (/ai/ → /ee/)

んじゃない, んじゃねえ and so on also work as a masculine negative imperative, but that's not how your sentence is working.

But can also it be "Isn't it" んじゃない?

@LionGate Yes, "招いてんじゃねえ?" can mean "Isn't it that someone has invited someone?" depending on the context.

ている is...resultative state here. If I say "会長は招いている。" then it means "the boss was invited," but why is it not 招いた here, and why is it not 招いた in the dialogue above?

@BigRigz 会長は招いている means either "Kaicho has invited them" or "I/we/they have invited Kaicho". There is little difference between 招いたんじゃねえ and 招いてんじゃねえ in the given context.

Does that make 招く a stative verb?

@BigRigz No. A stative verb is a verb that describes a state without ている.

Your not gonna like my latest question then.

Verb + んじゃない is not always imperative negative. In this case, it is simply a negation. So, your interpretation of the sentence is correct.
Now, how can you distinguish between the imperative negative and a plain negative. The key is to consider who is performing the action of the verb. To clarify, let's specify the subject of verb(招く in this case):

客だから(俺が)招いてんじゃねえ -- I invited you not because you are a client.

Since the one doing the inviting(招く) is 俺(I), the sentence is a plain negative, not an imperative.
If the verb refers to something the listener is doing, the sentence becomes an imperative negative.

(お前は)そんなことするんじゃねえ -- Don't do such a thing.


ん is used when explaining things.
じゃない is informal here, as じゃねえ.
Combine the two, it is "I am explaining why it is not X"; here, it is "You are living here because I am the host who is inviting you, not because you are the customer who has been invited."

I noted there were two ways to interpret ている here, and I assume this plays into the sort of rhetorical device in the dialogue.
